# MLFlow Model Serve Can't Find pyenv

Tags: mlflow

When following MLflow model serve example the {} I got the this error:

```
mlflow models serve -m  ./mlruns/0/c5af0a6e7c7944678a070026742b30ad/artifacts/model -p 8001
2023/02/22 09:12:14 INFO mlflow.models.flavor_backend_registry: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eliran/.local/bin/mlflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eliran/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/models/cli.py", line 104, in serve
    return get_flavor_backend(
  File "/home/eliran/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 226, in serve
    return self.prepare_env(local_path).execute(
  File "/home/eliran/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 100, in prepare_env
    activate_cmd = _get_or_create_virtualenv(
  File "/home/eliran/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/virtualenv.py", line 327, in _get_or_create_virtualenv
    _validate_pyenv_is_available()
  File "/home/eliran/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/virtualenv.py", line 63, in _validate_pyenv_is_available
    raise MlflowException(
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Could not find the pyenv binary. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation for installation instructions.
```

The solution was of add `pyenv` to the PATH.
`export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same is problem, to fix I ran

```bash
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
python -m  pip install virtualenv
PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. It would be great if you could also explain what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command it worked for me

```
mlflow models serve -m  ./mlruns/0/c5af0a6e7c7944678a070026742b30ad/artifacts/model -p 8001 --no-conda
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was of add pyenv to the PATH. export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"