# Mlflow on Docker cannot find pyenv binary

Tags: docker, pyenv, mlflow

I'm hosting a FastAPI service that retrains a model on docker. It uses Mlflow which stores the artifacts in local disk.

Upon invoking mlflow apis, mlflow complains that it cannot find pyenv; which I've tried installing with the automatic installer and with pip but to no avail.

{Pseudo API Function}

```
def retrain(Model):
    raw = my_extraction()
    preprocessed = my_preprocess( raw )
    model = Model.fit( preprocessed )
    with mlflow.start_run():
        run_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id
        mlflow.pyfunc.log_model( model, artifact_path="model" )
    cmd = f'mlflow models serve -m runs:/{run_id}/model -p 12345'
    subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=None, start_new_session=True)
    return None
```

{Dockerfile}

```
FROM prefecthq/prefect:2-python3.9
WORKDIR /app

# Some application related files
ADD . .


RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y gcc && apt-get install -y git

RUN curl https://pyenv.run | bash
ENV PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS --enable-shared
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
RUN echo 'export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:PATH"'>> /root/.bashrc && \ 
    echo 'eval "(pyenv init -)"'>> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"'>> /root/.bashrc
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /root/.bashrc"]

# upgrade PIP 
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \ 
    pip install virtualenv
    
# install python packages 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=80"]
```

{Stacktrace}

```
INFO mlflow.models.flavor_backend_registry: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/mlflow", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(cli())

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__

|     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
|     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
|     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
|     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
|     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
|     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/models/cli.py", line 105, in serve
|     return get_flavor_backend(
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 231, in serve
|     return self.prepare_env(local_path).execute(
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 105, in prepare_env
|     activate_cmd = _get_or_create_virtualenv(
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/utils/virtualenv.py", line 327, in _get_or_create_virtualenv
|     _validate_pyenv_is_available()
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/utils/virtualenv.py", line 63, in _validate_pyenv_is_available
|     raise MlflowException(
| mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Could not find the pyenv binary. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation for installation instructions.
```

Tried the following resources:

1. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation
2. [MLFlow Model Serve Can't Find pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75534090/mlflow-model-serve-cant-find-pyenv)
3. https://gist.github.com/jprjr/7667947

Same error after tweaking the Dockerfile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.